# TypeError when changing colors in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

So I'm experimenting in pygame and wrote some code for a rectangle that slowly changes color

```
a = 4
b = 3
c = 2

#some irrelevant code later

    if color[0]+a < 255:
        color[0] += a
    else:
        a *= -1
    if color[1]+b < 255:
        color[1] += b
    else:
        b *= -1
    if color[2]+c < 255:
        color[2] += c
    else:
        c *= -1
```

a, b, and c as the speed of change for red, green, and, blue.

The problem is that for some reason it will give me a TypeError: Invalid color argument after a few seconds of the program running, usually when the color is very blue. I don't see any reason an invalid color argument would appear.

Comment: What is the type of the `color` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect a `ValueError` instead of a `TypeError`, but it looks like what's happening is that if we take `a = 4` and work with `color[0]`

- `color[0]` == 250, so gets changed to `254`
- `color[0]` == 254, so stays the same, `a` gets changed to `-4`
- `color[0]` == 254, so gets changed to `250`
- ... keeps substracting `4`....

And I'm not sure -4 is a valid colour...

**maybe look at using**

```
>>> from itertools import izip, cycle
>>> a = range(0, 20, 4) + range(20, 0, -4)
>>> b = range(0, 20, 3) + range(20, 0, -3)
>>> c = range(0, 20, 2) + range(20, 0, -2)
>>> test = izip(cycle(a), cycle(b), cycle(c))
>>> for i in range(30):
    print next(test)

(0, 0, 0)
(4, 3, 2)
(8, 6, 4)
(12, 9, 6)
(16, 12, 8)
(20, 15, 10)
(16, 18, 12)
(12, 20, 14)
(8, 17, 16)
(4, 14, 18)
(0, 11, 20)
(4, 8, 18)
(8, 5, 16)
(12, 2, 14)
(16, 0, 12)
(20, 3, 10)
(16, 6, 8)
(12, 9, 6)
(8, 12, 4)
(4, 15, 2)
(0, 18, 0)
(4, 20, 2)
(8, 17, 4)
(12, 14, 6)
(16, 11, 8)
(20, 8, 10)
(16, 5, 12)
(12, 2, 14)
(8, 0, 16)
(4, 3, 18)
```

Comment: @user1825408 Put some example code in there - think that's effectively the same as what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You are eventually getting to -ve colours. You reverse the direction if the colour gets too high, but not if the colour gets too low. Check to make sure it is also greater than 0.

```
if 0 < color[0]+a < 255:
    color[0] += a
else:
    a *= -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a TypeError, somewhere else in your code (maybe far away from where the `TypeError` actually occurs!), you are redefining `color`. For example, something like

```
color = 'blue'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Color class](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html)

```
from pygame.locals import Color

def color_rand(c):
    try:
        c.r += random.randint(0,10)
    except ValueError:
        c.r = 0

bg = Color(0,0,0)
bg = color_rand(bg)
```